# How to delete a DB in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql and am trying to clean some of the databases I created for testing purposes.

I tried :

```
databases collect delete;
```

Comment: [`DROP {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [IF EXISTS] db_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-database.html)

Comment: Have you even tried to look at the documentation of your database system?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `phpmysql` interface or you can run the command

```
drop database dbname;
```